# Hover Intent not working

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I recheck my code many times and I use something similar on another website where it is working.
Here is the link to the site:
http://bit.ly/34XhDb

```
    //add hover intent to dropdown
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var config = {
sensitivity: 3, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
interval: 100, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval
over: doOpen, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)
timeout: 1200, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
out: doClose // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
};

function doOpen() {
    jQuery(this).addClass("hover");
    jQuery('ul:first',this).fadeIn();
}
function doClose() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("hover");
    jQuery('ul:first',this).fadeOut();
}
jQuery("ul#main_catnav li").hoverIntent(config);

});
```

I checked with debug but does not appear to be a conflict, plus the class of hover is being applied.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the plugin, it's your CSS, you have this:

```
ul#main_catnav ul { /*...other styles... */ display: none; }
ul#main_catnav li:hover ul { display: block}
```

So when the mouse leaves that `:hover` isn't being applied anymore and it's hidden instantly by CSS, not JavaScript.  To get it working you need to add `li.hover` as well, like this:

```
ul#main_catnav ul { /*...other styles... */ display: none; }
ul#main_catnav li:hover ul, ul#main_catnav li.hover ul { display: block}
```

Which accounts for the element either being hovered by the mouse, or having the class `.hover` like you're giving it with the `hoverIntent` plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll need to make some fine tune but it finally works.